# Linker error Duplicate Symbol when trying to link libFlurryAds

Tags: c++, ios, linker, admob, flurry

I am working on an iOS game and have admob / iAd / and flurry integrated for serving ads. I am using admob mediation for serving ads from these providers.

The problem is that when I try to test against the simulator I get a lot of linker errors like this . . .

duplicate symbol _utf8_check_string in:
    /Users/omersaeed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EscapeToArae-drmhiearnycapsfamyakifandjod/Build/Intermediates/EscapeToArae.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/EscapeToArae.build/Objects-normal/i386/utf.o
    /Users/omersaeed/projects/gamechefs/cocos2d-x-2.2/projects/e2a/customlibs/Flurry-iOS-4.3.0/FlurryAds/libFlurryAds_4.3.0.a(libExternalSDKs.a-i386-master.o)

All errors are about duplicate symbols and all are related to the libFlurryAds library.

The interesting part is that I can link and run the game perfectly if I run directly on the device.

Removing the Flurry libs solves the problem.

Any idea why the issue pops up when I run on the simulator and not when I run on the device?

Comment: summery ->build phase-> resource .o are .a files are add two times or those files refer two time .

Comment: Awesome dude! Your pointer lead to the solution. I did indeed have duplicates. If you post an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So eventually figured out that I was using a library called jansson (for JSON parsing) in source form, the same library is apparently included in the libFlurryAds and thus I was getting duplicate symbol errors. I eventually removed jansson and replaced it with another simpler JSON reader.